# How to design the interface for the Model in Model-View-Controller?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, interface, model

I understand how the MVC pattern works, but I've always had this question. If you have a big Model with many functions delegated to various classes, do you have to define a big monolithic interface with all the methods to manipulate and query the Model?

Or, can that model be partitioned to many models, that talk to each other, and then you can manipulate them with their respective controllers?

Thanks

Comment: I use symfony (a PHP MVC framework) and the model is expressed as many separate classes (initially four for each table in the database). I don't see where a "monolithic" interface would go.

Comment: For what i've seen, a model basically reflects a table or an entity, with CRUD methods. I'm interested in this question so i'll follow along.

Answer (score 2):

The "ViewModel" concept may be helpful here -- it's also referred to as "view specific model" by Phil Haack in the book "[Professional ASP.NET MVC3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118076583)".

A lot of auto-tooling or "scaffolding" generators look to create a single page/interface but there is nothing preventing you from making a multi-stage process for a large model.

One option would be to create View Models for each stage of the process (ie. BigProcessPartAViewModel, BigProcessPartBViewModel, etc) and then generate a controller that process each of these with separate views.  Obviously you'll need to manage state across multiple stages, perhaps with a database or session.

Additionally, your model is your model... it is NOT data access.  So you may need to have an additional model that handles in-process state as well as a data access design that allows for a multi-phase transaction.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know that. I'll have to take a look a that later. But that approach will definitely be an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that says that your Model needs to be a single class or entity.

For example, in Spring MVC, the model is basically a `Map` that you construct in the Controller, with keys and values.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. It's just that the examples I've seen all the controllers talk to just one model.

Answer (score 1):

Interface segregation is one of the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) which stands for 5 basic principles of object-oriented programming and design. It says that if your interface becomes too 'fat' it needs to be split into smaller and more specific interfaces. More details on [Interface segregation wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)

Comment: Yeah, that's basically the reason why I'm asking the question, because it would be a really tedious to deal with monolithic interface, and not elegant either.